# PostgreSQL missing FROM-CLAUSE entry

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
WITH sb AS (
    SELECT "shiftId", "sb.bookings"."state", "visibleAt" FROM bookings
    JOIN "memberConnections" ON "bookings"."memberId" = "memberConnections"."memberId"
    WHERE "shiftId"= 1714
)

SELECT
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) from sb where "bookings.state"='MATCHED'), 0) as matched FROM SB
```

It tells me: `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sb.bookings"`
`LINE 2:     SELECT "shiftId", "sb.bookings"."state", "visibleAt" FRO...`

I wrote it as `"sb.bookings"."state"` because state is in both tables, but it didn't want to allow me to write it as `"bookings"."state"` ( I don't know why either )

Does anyone have any ideea about this?

Comment: Why are you using double quotes around all your identifies?  That just clutters the query and can lead to unidentified identifiers.

Comment: double quotes are needed because columns are written in camel case.

Comment: Otherwise, it would throw an error @GordonLinoff, since we're using camelCase

Comment: Why are you using camel case, which makes it even harder to write queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CTE is prefacing the `state` column with an identifier which does not exist.  And, you can simplify your final query:

```
WITH sb AS (
    SELECT shiftId, b.state, visibleAt
    FROM bookings b
    INNER JOIN memberConnections m
        ON b.memberId = m.memberId
    WHERE shiftId = 1714
)

SELECT
    COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS matched
FROM sb
WHERE
    state = 'MATCHED';
```

The quoted version of your CTE:

```
WITH sb AS (
    SELECT "shiftId", b."state", "visibleAt"
    FROM "bookings" b
    INNER JOIN "memberConnections" m
        ON b."memberId" = m."memberId"
    WHERE "shiftId" = 1714
)
```

Comment: Your query would throw an error if you didn't wrap `memberConnections` in double quotes :D

Comment: I gave you a version with double quotes, in case you need it.  But, maybe you should stop making your columns case sensitive.  This is the not the default behavior of Postgres anyway.

Comment: So yeah, now it's saying that `ERROR:  column reference "state" is ambiguous`, so this is why I used `sb.bookings.state` (Because `bookings.state` doesn't work), and now we're back to the main question again, it'll throw the FROM-clause missing entry error

Comment: Just prefix `state` with an alias from one of the tables (whichever one you want).  Why did you not post your table structure in the question?

Comment: What do you mean, prefix state? state is not a table